# JPA Custom Query

Tags: jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I need your help. Basically I want to create a custom query for a view I made that contains most of the data needed by the client. The tricky part here is that the client can specify which columns to include in the search. A sample query would be like:

```
SELECT distinct s.empno FROM SesdbAllView s 
WHERE  s.lastname IN :lname  AND  s.examTaken IN :exam  AND
s.training IN :train  AND  s.trainingFrom BETWEEN :from AND :to  AND
s.eligibility IN :elig  AND  s.profession IN :prof
```

So I tried translating this to Criteria API but still stuck on how to do it especially in the BETWEEN keywords (where I check a range of a `Date` and also another for a `Integer`). When it comes to the IN keywords I'm not sure if I did it correctly as well.

My current code now is:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<SesdbAllView> r = cq.from(SesdbAllView.class); 
    Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : parameters.entrySet()) {
        if (param.getValue() instanceof List) {
            Expression<String> exp = r.get(param.getKey()); 
            p = cb.and(p, exp.in((List<String>)param.getValue()));
        } else if (param.getValue() instanceof DateFromTo) {
            DateFromTo fromTo = (DateFromTo) param.getValue();
            p = cb.between(r.get(param.getKey()).as(Date.class),fromTo.getFrom(),fromTo.getTo());          
        } else if (param.getValue() instanceof IntegerFromTo) {
            IntegerFromTo fromTo = (IntegerFromTo) param.getValue(); 
            p = cb.between(r.get(param.getKey()).as(Integer.class),fromTo.getFrom(),fromTo.getTo());
        } else {
            p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(r.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue()));
        }
    } 
    cq.distinct(true);
    cq.multiselect(r.get("empNo"))
            .where(p); 
    List<Tuple> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: Are you really need `BETWEEN` statement? I usually avoid it as in different database it has a different meaning about whether upper and lower bounds are included. Try just to use two separate conditions for upper and lower bounds. And try to search for `cast` operator alternative in criteria builder. Also, I often use QueryDSL instead of criteria builder.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev that is not true. The JPA specification says it very clear that both the upper and lower bounds are included. Look at the "Chapter 4.6.8 Between Expressions" in the JPA 2.0 spec.